# Python for loops only every second Item

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

never had such a problem and do not know how to solve or even call it...

```
types = [105000, 105001, 105002, 105003, 105004, 105005, 105006, 105007]
for type in types:
    print type
```

prints only

```
105000
105002
105004
105006
```

but I don't know why.

using a function to generate an array from input like

```
self.arrSplit(105000,105001,105002,105003,105004,105005,105006,105007)
```

function:

```
    def arrSplit(self, arr):
        itms = []
        for it in arr.split(','):
            tt = it.split('-')
            if (len(tt) >= 2 and int(tt[0]) < int(tt[1])):
                for i in range(int(tt[0]), int(tt[1])+1):
                    itms.append(i)
            else:
                itms.append(int(tt[0]))
        return itms
```

to complete this the code looks like this (its the minimum)

```
types = self.arrSplit(105000,105001,105002,105003,105004,105005,105006,105007)
print types
for type in types:
print type
```

prints:

```
[105000, 105001, 105002, 105003, 105004, 105005, 105006, 105007]
105000
105002
105004
105006
```

Comment: That is not possible. Are you sure that this is the code that produce that output?

Comment: Works just fine for me... Your indentation is broken, though, but I guess that's an artefact of how you put it on SO

Comment: Please give the input (is that the '1,2,3,4' you mention?), the expected return value and the actually return value of `arrSplit`.

Comment: input to that function is     105000,105001,105002,105003,105004,105005,105006,105007 when i print it to console it is showing me it right but when i loop through its only getting every 2nd element wich is weird

Comment: Are you using a 64bit executable on a 32bit OS ?

Comment: No i am connecting via ssh to my debian7 vp-server, never had problems before when i used this function, only now and only there

Answer (score 0):

For the for loop you should use this:

```
types = [105000, 105001, 105002, 105003, 105004, 105005, 105006, 105007]
for numbers in types:
    print numbers
```

This worked for me, but I can't explain why it only printed evens.