# pyqtgraph: for item in <GLViewWidget instance>.items brings up only every second item

Tags: python, for-loop, pyqtgraph

I could reproduce the problem I have in the pyqtgraph example GLLinPlotItem.py. 
I just added the lines

```
print (w.items)     

for item in w.items:
    if (type (item) == gl.GLLinePlotItem): 
        print (item)
        w.removeItem (item)
```

after the for loop that loads the plot with the GLLinePlotItems.

while print (w.items) prints all items my for loop prints and deletes only every second one.

I found this thread: [Python for loops only every second Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813004/python-for-loops-only-every-second-item) but there is no solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Martin

Edit: if you comment w.removeItem it prints all items.

Comment: `Modifying a set during iteration can lead to skipped elements, repeated elements, and other weirdness. Never rely on such behavior.` - See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61221502/1000551)

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for your answer, you got the solution, I found myself also and edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found myself:
removeItem changes the list, moving every subsequent item one index forward, while the loop index remains the same. So for in loops internally are only loop through the index. I thought they take into account when the list changes. learned something new again :-)
So my solution is going through the list from the rear, so removing an item does not affect the index because it counts from the front:

```
itm_cnt = len (w.items)
idx = itm_cnt - 1
print (itm_cnt)    
while (idx >= 0):
    if (type (w.items [idx]) == gl.GLLinePlotItem): 
        print (idx, w.items [idx])
#        w.removeItem (w.items [idx])
        del w.items [idx]
    idx -= 1
```

I hope this helps somebody else.
Martin